# Who was the "green-eyes" that Arya was supposed to murder?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

We saw Melisandre tell Arya:

> "I see a darkness in you. And in that darkness, eyes staring back at me: brown eyes, blue eyes, green eyes. Eyes you’ll shut forever."

and sure Arya

> killed Walder Frey (brown eyes) and the night king (blue eyes)

Did the writers include this only to raise theories such as Arya killing Cersei or Daenerys?

What is the plot about the green eyes?

Comment: Why does there need to be a specific person with each color of eyes?  Mel's point was "you're going to kill a lot of people" and that was absolutely true.  Arya even said as much when they met in Winterfell.

Comment: Are you asking for answers that start from the assumption that prophecies on *GoT*, or at least this specific one, are fundamentally and unalterably accurate?